# setState, add values to a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set a json object with setState, that adds a new key value pair with every for loop.

The object will look something like this eventually.

```
const data = [
  { accuracy: 5, timeTaken: .8 },
  { accuracy: -120, timeTaken: .5 },
  { accuracy: -170, timeTaken: .5 },
  { accuracy: 140, timeTaken: .6},
  { accuracy: 150, timeTaken: .7 },
  { accuracy: 110, timeTaken: .1},
];
```

The current function looks a bit like this.,

```
 if (overall !=null) {
    // var percentageCorrect = (100*(LevStein(results[3].question,results[3].answer)/results[3].question.length))
    const [TestData, setTestData] = useState({})
for (var l = 0; l < overall.length; l++) {
  var results = JSON.parse(overall[l].testdetails.result)



    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

      // setTestData({...x:(100*(LevStein(results[i].question,results[i].answer)/results[i].question.length)),})
      console.log("accuracy: ",(100*(LevStein(results[i].question,results[i].answer)/results[i].question.length))," timeTaken: ",results[i].timeTaken)   
    
    }
  }

    // JSON.parse(overall[0].testdetails.result);
  }
```

How do i just add a new value to TestData to replicate the above json object ?

Comment: your data is an array of objects, not an object itself. you can directly push to the array

Answer (score 1):

The `useState` hook ***can't*** be called conditionally, this breaks the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). It needs to be called in the body of the function component.

Since `results` is an array you can replace or append it to the `testData` state (*which should be an array, btw). Use a functional state update to shallow copy the previous state, and map the `results` array to the object values you want.

```
const [TestData, setTestData] = useState([]);

...
...

if (overall !== null) {
  overall.forEach(({ testdetails }) => {
    const results = JSON.parse(testdetails.result);

    setTestData(data => [
      ...data,
      ...results.map(({ answer, question, timeTaken }) => ({
        accuracy: 100 * (LevStein(question, answer) / question.length),
        timeTaken
      }))
    ]);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the object like this:

```
setTestData([...testData, { new object }])
```

Comment: `setTestData` is called in a loop so this code may not work 100% as you expect.